# About Linking Number

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I'm looking for some references about [Linking Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number). I already know these

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinkingNumber.html

http://www.matapp.unimib.it/~ricca/publications/2011/JKTR11.pdf

Anything will be helpful, thank you.

Comment: +1 For getting inspiration from 'the genius of hard work'.

Comment: Thank you Git Gud, in fact I do feel a lot like him while studying math.

Comment: Likewise.${{}}$

Comment: @Integral I feel you. I stubbornly study discrete mathematics day and night to overcome my inability to do calculus.

Comment: @Alexander Gruber Mathematics is a game for those stubborn or really genius, but genius are rare. I think most of mathematicians are hard workers more than anything else.

Comment: ([tag:reference-request]) should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).